# Как настроить .htaccess под MVC?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, redirect, rewrite

.htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

В OpenServer все нормально работает, а на веб-хостинге выдает ошибку http error 500. Хочу что бы .htaccess открывал другие файлы. Например domain.ru/payment/

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 500 означает ошибку сервера (проблема с настройками). При этом должно появиться сообщение в error_log с подробностями ошибки (в какой строке обнаружена ошибка и в чем суть ошибки). Если такого сообщения/лога нету, значит надо обязательно настроить.

Без подробностей из лога можно только предположить что за проблема у вас:

1. Не установлен/включен модуль mode_rewrite. Посмотрите список модулей `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`
2. Отсутствует разрешение на использование директив mod_rewrite в `.htaccess` См. описание директивы `AllowOverride` (должно быть разрешение `FileInfo`)